# Fixed number of rows in MySql

Tags: mysql

How to set the maximum number of SQL records to 10 and automatically delete the last record if a new one is added.

Comment: I know this may not be important, but why would you like to do so? Wouldn't it just be easier to take the 10 last entries, or maybe the 10 entries with highest id or something. Thinking like (`select * from sometable order by id desc limit 1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete all records except last ten inserted with a single query that you run when you want

```
delete from table where id < (select * from (select id from table order by id desc limit 9,1) as tab)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no such feature in MySQL. You have to program it yourself, either in your application, or in the database by writing a trigger or stored procedure.

Count the current number of rows (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table`), if it's greater than 10, `DELETE FROM table ORDER BY somecol LIMIT 1` to remove one.

Answer (score 1):

Add a date/time field with the insert date and time.  Then run a trigger on insert to delete the top 1 rows and sort by date descending.

Comment: but its not possible in C#... it get complex if I add code for date and time in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep all the records, and only return the 10 most recent. You then write a cleanup procedure that periodically removes the older ones.

`SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10`